# An explicative definition of what is meant by $\{A_i\}_{i\in I}$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

What does $\{A_i\}_{i\in I}$ mean exactly?

I know it's an index, but what exactly is that?

Comment: You can think of it as being the collection of all $A_i$. For instance, take $I = \Bbb N$ and $A_i = \{i\}$, then $\{A_i\}_{i\in I}$ would be comprised of all of the singleton sets $\{i\}$, i.e. $\{A_i\}_{i\in I} = \{\{i\}:i\in\Bbb N\}$.

Comment: The definition, similarly to that of a sequence $\left(a_n\right)_{n\in \mathbb N}$, is that $\{A_i\}_{i\in I}$ is a function $A$ whose domain is $I$. And just like sequences, instead of denoting the image of an element $i$ of $I$ by $A(i)$, one denotes it by $A_i$. Many times abuses are made and people write $\{A_i\}_{i\in I}$ to denote the image of the function $A$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It denotes a collection $\mathscr A$ of objects, and it means there is surjection $f: I\rightarrow \mathscr A$. One often has that $f$ is injective, so that objects $f(i) = A_i\in \mathscr A$ and $f(j)= A_j\in\mathscr A$  corresponding to distinct indices $i\in I$ and $j\in I$ are themselves distinct, but this need not be the case.

It simply means that there are sufficiently many members of $I$ to enumerate the members of $\mathscr A$.

Answer (score 2):

To supplement MPW's answer and the comments, the other important detail about this notation is absolutely nothing is implied about the cardinality (size) of the index set $I$.   It could be a finite collection,  countably infinite collection,  uncountably infinite....we use the term "an arbitrary collection" to indicate any particular size.